# Using jQuery(this).next() to show/hide the next nested UL in a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Whenever "section" is clicked, I would like for the next UL (sub-menu) to disappear (or reappear). I can get a simple P tag to disappear outside of this tree, but I am trying to use the jQuery next(); function. How can I select this element with jQuery. I thought that:

```
$(".section").click(function() {
   $(this).next('ul').hide();
});
```

Would work, but it doesn't... here is the HTML:

```
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="main-menu">
        <li class="section">
            Section 1
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="z-index: 3;">
                <li>
                    Section 1A
                </li>
                <li>
                    Section 1B
                </li>
                <li>
                    Section 1C
                </li>
                <li>
                    Back
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="section">
            Section 2
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="z-index: 2;">
                <li>
                    Section 2A
                </li>
                <li>
                    Section 2B
                </li>
                <li>
                    Section 2C
                </li>
                <li>
                    Back
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Update*

Find() worked fine. But now I am wondering how I can use the li element with the text "Back" in it to toggle the sub-menu off. I have added a class "back" to the last LI element on each sub-menu list, but jQuery can't seem to find it and apply the CSS. Here is what I have:

```
//this code works
$(".section").click(function() {
   $(this).find('ul').css( "left", "0" );
});

//this code doesn't locate the previous UL (i also tried (".sub-menu").css()
$('.back').click(function() {
   $('.back').prev('ul').css( "left", "485" );
});

//html:

            <li class="section">
            Section 1
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="z-index: 3;">
                <li>
                    <a href="#section1a">Section 1A</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section1b">Section 1B</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#section1c">Section 1C</a>
                </li>
                <li class="back">
                    <a href="#back">Back</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: try `$(this).find('ul').hide();`

Comment: Also try `.toggle` for hiding and showing instead of `.hide`.

Comment: try @KartikeyaKhosla 's answer the reason yours is not working is that in the .next() function you select the next sibling of the currently selected element. in your case you select the first `<li>` which will give you the second `<li>` when calling next(). find() instead also digs into child elements and looks for the given selector. furthermore, toggle() is good for hiding and showing if you want to implement both of it on the same click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you use `next()` which looks at the next sibling, where you instead want to look at the children. To target them, you can use the `find(filter)` function. By finding the `ul`, you can use `toggle()` or `slideToggle` to toggle it's visibility.

I've also added an extra click function on the children. That prevents that clicking the child closes the sub-menu.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.section').click( function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
  }).children().click( function() {
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="section">
      Section 1
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="z-index: 3;">
        <li>Section 1A</li>
        <li>Section 1B</li>
        <li>Section 1C</li>
        <li>Back</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="section">
      Section 2
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="z-index: 2;">
        <li>Section 2A</li>
        <li>Section 2B</li>
        <li>Section 2C</li>
        <li>Back</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks all, toggle() or slideToggle is definitely the way to go, I just used hide() because I wanted to quickly hide the element to know that it was working.

Comment: Ted, if I would like the "back" child to work, but not the other three elements, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Guessing that back should close the submenu: `$('.sub-menu li:last').click(function(){ $(this).parent().slideUp(); });`

Answer (score 4):

`next` affects the tag's siblings, i.e. the other `.section` tags, while the `<li>` tags you want to operate on are in reality its descendants. Thus you should use

```
$(".section").click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

The `find` and `toggle` method are the ones you need.